# Description of tags on the tag page does not always start at the beginning

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

While I was looking through the [popular tag page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rpBo.png) I noticed some inconsistent behaviour of the descriptive text below the tag.

For example:

The [adobe-fireworks](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-fireworks) tag looks like this:
[image]

This matches the text shown on mouse-over:
[image]

However, the [rgb](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rgb) tag looks like this:
[image]

It misses the first few words, which do show on mouse-over:
[image]

I find this annoying as my plan was to look through popular tags and see if I can improve the tag-wikis. However, this inconsistent showing of the description slows down the process a bit as I sometimes have to mouse-over and wait for the animation.

I'm on OSX 10.8.5 and use Firefox v28.0.

<sub>Note: the tags mentioned are just chosen as an example. I was not planning on editing those wikis.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Here is the relevant Meta Stack Exchange post: [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82700/216955) (and a bunch of related discussions listed in the Linked section).

As explained, it's meant to reduce redundancy so that the tag excerpt is as concise as possible.